# Parallax Background resizing for various resolutions in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, parallax

I am making a side scrolling game using libgdx. I have used a parallax background... currently when I am testing the game for 800 x 480 resolution.. its working fine... but when tested for other higher resolutions like 1280 x 720... I am noticing that the background is not expanding itself for height and producing a bad effect at the top of the game screen.

I found the code at the official site of LibGDX

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1795

and it's working perfectly for the current resolution.

Actually I have created an ImageAtlas and my background is a TextureRegion inside it. I think.. there is some problem with sizing...Should I use different sizes for different resolution. Is there any way to use a single parallax background that can be well expanded for all devices.

Here is the screenshot for 1280 x 720 resolution

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problem. The background clearly *does* expand to the top by repeating itself. That's what a parallax background does...

Comment: A way to fix this would be to make the wallpaper a separate sprite that is drawn to repeat and fill the background, and have the bookshelf and floor be other sprites that are drawn individually instead of all drawn together as a single image.

Comment: yes.. this seems to be a better idea.. if i would not get success with the wall as parallax.. I can make the bottom floor a parallax and set the wall as the screen background. Thank you...